# How do I update a SQL row given an ID with LINQ to SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, crud

Given this schema:

```
Fruits
 - FruitID       INT PK
 - FruitName     NVARCHAR(30)
 - FruitStatusID INT NULL FK: Statuses

Statuses
 - StatusID      INT PK
 - StatusName    NVARCHAR(30)
```

If I have a `FruitID` in hand (just an int, not a Fruit object), how do I update the `FruitName` and null out `FruitStatusID` without loading the Fruit object from the database first?

Note: [this solution](http://tonesdotnetblog.wordpress.com/2008/08/15/linq-to-entities-disconnected-crud/) gets me pretty far, but I can't figure out how to null out a FK column.

Answers in C# or VB, thanks!

Comment: This feels like a case of premature optimization.  Go with straight SQL if you're that concerned about performance.  You can mix ado.net command execution and LINQ to SQL in a single transaction if necessary.

Comment: This is a simplified example. Also, if I can easily avoid retrieving a record from the database just to update it, I will--I don't think that's premature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but seems unnecessarily complicated:

```
''//initialize the values I'm going to null out to something
Dim Tag As Data_Tag = New Data_Tag() With {
  .Data_Tag_ID = DataTagID, 
  .Last_Error_DateTime = New DateTime(), 
  .Last_Error_Message = "", 
  .Last_Error_Severity_Type_ID = -1 }

''//start change tracking
DB.Data_Tags.Attach(Tag)

''//record changes to these properties (must be initialized above)
Tag.Last_Error_DateTime = Nothing
Tag.Last_Error_Message = Nothing
Tag.Last_Error_Severity_Type_ID = Nothing

DB.SubmitChanges()
```

Surely there's a better way!

(note: the weird comment syntax is solely for the code highliger--it doesn't like VB-style comments)